# How to display a user friendly ANTLR parsing error

Tags: parsing, antlr

I would like to display a user friendly pasing error in ANTLR4.

Here is a sample of valid text for my parser:

```
aaaa AND bbb AND @FD $sysdate
```

When I remove dollar $ I have a nice parsing error

```
aaaa AND bbb AND @FD sysdate
line 1:21 mismatched input 'sysdate' expecting {' ', '$'}
```

When I make a typo in sysdate I have a nice parsing error

```
aaaa AND bbb AND @FD $sysABCdate
line 1:22 token recognition error at: 'sysABCdate'
line 1:32 missing {'sysdate', 'SYSDATE'} at '<EOF>'
```

When I miss AND before @FD

```
aaaa AND bbb YYY @FD $sysdate
```

I have actual error message

```
line 1:0 token recognition error at: 'aaaa AND bbb YYY @FD $sysdate'
line 1:29 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting BODY_WITH_FIELD_CODE
```

while I would expect something more user friendly like

```
token error at YYY, missing {'AND'}
```

Here is my ANTLR definition

```
//rules
mainQ : base EOF ;
base : BODY_WITH_FIELD_CODE filling_date_condition;
filling_date_condition : ' '* sys_date_minus_number;
sys_date_minus_number : sys_date_with_dollar_prefix;
sys_date_with_dollar_prefix : '$'('sysdate'|'SYSDATE');

//TOKENS
BODY_WITH_FIELD_CODE : .+? ('and'|'AND') WS+ FD_WITH_AT;
FD_WITH_AT : '@' FD;
fragment WS : ' ';
fragment FD : 'fd'|'FD';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the trouble is, the parser is telling the truth - it only discovered that it cannot match the input at the very end of it.

The three basic ways an input mismatch can happen are:

- A rule requires that there is a specific token, but a different token is on input

  - Then the error is thrown where the token was expected
- A rule has two or more alternatives (i.e. paths which the parser can follow), and the input matches neither of those

  - Then the error (`NoViableAlternative`) is thrown at the point in the input where the input wouldn't match any alternative
- A rule requires more tokens, but we're already at the end of input

  - Then the error is thrown at the end of input

The `.+?` is the culprit here. It non-greedily matches anything. What happened here is:

- It mathced `aaaa AND bbb` as expected

  - That's where it stopped in all previous cases, since it saw an `AND @FD`
- But this last time, the `AND @FD` was not present, so the non-greediness did not take effect and the rule kept consuming input, until it consumed `aaaa AND bbb YYY @FD $sysdate`
- And there it finally realized that there's no way to match the input since it expects `AND` but sees an `EOF`